# Globus Toolkit virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, globus-toolkit

Is there anyplace where one can download a virtual machine containing a working install of some Linux distro with Globus Toolkit and some development tools (Java) for testing purposes? A real deployment of a grid is more complicated but I just need something portable, for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to http://workspace.globus.org/vm/marketplace.html appears to be broken now. I think the new location is http://scienceclouds.org/marketplace/.

Answer (score 1):

The [Virtual Data Toolkit](http://vdt.cs.wisc.edu/) is not a virtual machine image, but it is a nice distro of tons of grid tools (including Globus) which is *very* easy to install.  I use it all the time, and love it.

From [their website](http://vdt.cs.wisc.edu/):

> The Virtual Data Toolkit (VDT) is an
> ensemble of grid software that can be
> easily installed and configured. In
> our experience, installing grid
> software from scratch is challenging
> and time consuming. The goal of the
> VDT is to make it as easy as possible
> for users to deploy, maintain and use
> grid software. Ideally, you just type
> a single-command and you can
> immediately access grid resources or
> provide your resources to others. In
> reality, it is a bit more work than
> that, but not much.
>
> ...
>
> The VDT contains a wide variety of
> grid software as well as the software
> that it depends on. For example, the
> VDT includes common grid software like
> Condor-G ® and Globus ®, and VOMS, and
> much more. But it also provides
> supporting software like Apache,
> Tomcat, and MySQL. There are also many
> other software components that help
> run grid sites, like software to
> update CA certificate revocation lists
> (fetch-crl), software to assist with
> local authorization policies (GUMS)
> accounting software, and much more.